# Acessar itens de uma tupla no Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, tupla

Estou tentando acessar um item de uma tupla no meu template para imprimir o nome da tecnologia e não o numero correspondente.

Meu model onde a tupla esta:

```
TECHNOLOGY = (
  (0, "JavaScript"),
  (1, "Java"),
  (2, "Python"),
  (4, "Android"),
  (5, "Apple"),
  (6, "Other")
)


class Project(models.Model):
  project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
  github = models.CharField(max_length=500)
  technology = models.IntegerField(choices=TECHNOLOGY, default=6)
  summary = models.TextField(max_length=200)
  description = HTMLField()
  date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
  project_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['technology']

  def __str__(self):
      return self.title
```

Meu template onde preciso acessar:

```
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
              {% for project in project_list %}
                  {% for id, name in project.technology %}
                      <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic text-center">{{ name }} Projects</h1>
                      <p class="lead my-3 text-center">Projects made for programming studies or for college
                          assignments</p>
                  {% endfor %}
              {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quando você faz o for e acessa o atributo `technology` retorna o primeiro elemento das tuplas. Para não ocorrer isso, você precisa executar uma função no template html `{{project.get_technology_display }}` ou criar uma função no models para retornar os nomes das tecnologias invés dos IDs. Detalhe, mesmo você fazendo isso vai retornar um erro no seu segundo for, com a seguinte mensagem `'int' object is not iterable`, isso deve pelo fator que o seu objeto não é interável

#### Solução

Nesse caso vou criar uma função chamada `technology_verbose` dentro do models, assim tirando a necessidade de executar a função no template, através do `{{project.get_technology_display }}` (boa prática). E não irei utilizar o `for id name` pelo motivo que não é um `ManyToMany` e sim um `IntegerField` com apenas um valor do `choice`

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Project(models.Model):
    TECHNOLOGY = (
        (0, "JavaScript"),
        (1, "Java"),
        (2, "Python"),
        (4, "Android"),
        (5, "Apple"),
        (6, "Other"),
    )

    now = datetime.now()

    project_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    github = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    technology = models.IntegerField(choices=TECHNOLOGY, default=6)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    #description = HTMLField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    project_image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["technology"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    ## Função para retornar os nomes das tecnologias
    def technology_verbose(self):
        return dict(Project.TECHNOLOGY)[self.technology]
```

**html**

```
<link  rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
    {% for project in project_list %}
            <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic text-center">{{ project.technology_verbose }} Projects</h1>
            <p class="lead my-3 text-center">Projects made for programming studies or for college
                assignments</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

#### Visualização do HTML

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### GitHub

O Django possui a arquitetura **MTV** (Model, Template, View), sendo assim depende de vários fatores para funcionar. Vou deixar o GitHub e com o passo a passo de como rodar o projeto no README.

https://github.com/Kaiquenakao/stack-question/tree/master

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou :)

Comment: Fico feliz em saber ;)))